# Powershell: GCI to Find Files Recursively & Copy to Locations Where Filenames Exist

Tags: powershell

One of my external hard drives recently failed, and I had to employ a somewhat unorthodox procedure to recover my files. I won't bore you with details, but the end result was that after the recovery was complete, I had corrupt files in one directory structure on one drive, and intact files in the root of a folder elsewhere.

The task before me now is to figure out where the intact files are supposed to go. Everything has its correct filename, so the manual way to go about it is to search the corrupt directory for a filename, then open that file location, and copy the file in question back to where it belongs.

Sounds tedious, right?

What I'm looking to do is harness Powershell to make this process simpler. There are two ways I can see to making this work, but I'm not sure how to get Powershell to chain these commands together properly.

**Method #1:**

- Do a GCI call in the location with intact files, to figure out what all the filenames are
- Do a second GCI call in the location with corrupt files, to figure out what all those filenames are
- Where it finds a match between the two, I want it to copy from the first location (the folder with the flat structure), to the location where it found the match in the second, thus overwriting the corrupt file with the intact one

**Method #2:**

- Do a GCI call on each folder in the second location described above, to find out what the names of the folders (and folders only) are
- For each folder name it finds, I want it to run a Robocopy with the XL and Move parameters specified, so that it's only copying the files with matching filenames and progressively emptying out the first location--if there are any files left over when it's all done I'll know something got missed and needs manual attention

Either way, I'm imagining that a ForEach or ForEachObject will come into play with it, but I've got no idea how to properly pipe the values from one GCI call to another. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit to the rescue, but if anyone runs into this scenario here's how we solved it:

```
$goodFilesDir = '...'
$allBadFiles  = Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -File -Recurse

foreach ($badFile in $allBadFiles) {
    $movePath = [IO.Path]::Combine($goodFilesDir, $badFile.Name)

    if (![IO.File]::Exists($movePath)) {
        Write-Warning ("No good file found to replace '{0}'." -f $badFile.FullName)
        continue
    }

    Move-Item -Path $movePath -Destination $badFile.FullName -Force -WhatIf
}
```